# The right way to download large file with android service

Tags: android, performance, android-service

I created a Service for start the download of large file. I decided to create a ThreadPoolExecutor because in my app it's possibile download multiple files at once. In each thread I add a name the I send from my activity. I use this in case the user decides to stop a specific downlaod, in this way it's possible stop specific thread.

The code works but I wonder if it is correct or if there are better ways to accomplish this task.

Thanks in advance for the response.

```
public class DownloadService extends Service {

private static final String TAG = DownloadService.class.getName();
private Looper mServiceLooper;
private ServiceHandler mServiceHandler;
private LocalBroadcastManager mLocalBroadcastManager;
public static final String ACTION_MESSAGE = "it.myapplication.DownloadService.message";
public static final String ACTION_PROGRESS_BAR = "it.myapplication.DownloadService.progressbar";
private HandlerThread thread;

long id;

int NUMBER_OF_CORES = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
        NUMBER_OF_CORES * 2,
        NUMBER_OF_CORES * 2,
        60L,
        TimeUnit.SECONDS,
        new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>()
);

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    mLocalBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    final String nameThread = intent.getStringExtra("nameThread");
    boolean status = intent.getBooleanExtra("status", true);

    if (status) {
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                id = Thread.currentThread().getId();
                Log.d(TAG, TAG + " THREAD ID " + Thread.currentThread().getId());

                Thread.currentThread().setName(String.valueOf(nameThread));
                String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
                Log.d(TAG, TAG + " THREAD NAME " + name);

                Intent intent_send = new Intent(ACTION_MESSAGE);
                intent_send.putExtra("idThread", (int) id);
                intent_send.putExtra("nameThread", nameThread);
                mLocalBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent_send);

                downloadPackage(nameThread, (int) id);
            }
        });

    }
    else {
        Set<Thread> setOfThread = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
        for (Thread thread : setOfThread) {
            if (thread.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(nameThread)) {
                thread.interrupt();
            }
        }

        this.stopSelf();

    }


    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d(TAG, "DESTROY");
    super.onDestroy();
}

private void downloadPackage(String nameThread, int id) {
    Log.d("START DOWNLOAD", "START DOWNLOAD");
    String urlToDownload = "url";
    Intent intent_send = new Intent(ACTION_PROGRESS_BAR);

    NotificationManager mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle("Package Museum Download")
            .setContentText("Download in progress")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);


    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlToDownload);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        // this will be useful so that you can show a typical 0-100% progress bar
        int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

        // download the file
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        Log.d("DIR ", "DIR " + getApplicationContext().getFilesDir());

        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/data/data/it.myapplication/files/" + nameThread + ".pdf");

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        long total = 0;
        int count;
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            // publishing the progress....
            Bundle resultData = new Bundle();
            resultData.putInt("progress", (int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
            //Log.d(TAG, "PROGRESS DATA " + (int) (total * 100 / fileLength));

            intent_send.putExtra("progress", (int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
            mLocalBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent_send);

            mBuilder.setProgress(100, (int) (total * 100 / fileLength), false);
            // Displays the progress bar for the first time.
            mNotifyManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());

            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        // When the loop is finished, updates the notification
        mBuilder.setContentText("Download complete")
                .setProgress(0, 0, false);
        mNotifyManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());

        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        mNotifyManager.cancel(id);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: just use android DownloadManager http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html

Comment: thanks @yazan. I did not know